# How to configure Windows 10 to read signal from one antenna of the Wireless router?

Tags: device-manager

My HP laptop (with Windows 10) fails to recognize the network from the wireless router(two antennae). The same happened with ArchLinux installed. Editing one of the config files (***rtl8723be.conf***) in ***/etc/modprobe.d/*** to ***options rtl8723be ant_sel=1*** helped me connect to the network via single antenna uninterruptedly.

Is there a similar way to configure Windows 10 to pick the wireless router antenna in Windows Device Manager?

Comment: What do you mean by “the network from two antennae wireless router”? What relation do you mean between networks (=SSIDs?) and antennas?

Comment: I'm not sure of the network terminology. 
All I need is to select an antenna like I did in ArchLinux which helps me connect to the network.

Please help me frame my question in the case of ambiguity. Thanks.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your router. But whatever. Unless the Windows driver offers that option (look in Device Manager), it’s not going to work.

Comment: Yes. I understand that has nothing to do with my router. I want to know if there's any method to select the antenna like I mentioned the way it was done in ArchLinux.

Comment: Its about your wifi card. You have dual antenna chip with one antenna. [Realtek drivers for penguins had(have?) issues with antenna autodetect](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/34#issuecomment-172047409) hence workaround with manual selection. Windows drivers are supposed to have correct autodetection, so I'll guess you are left with usual driver update and fiddling in its settings.